# Why doesn't Array#each_with_object(0) work?

Tags: ruby

Why does using `0` as the argument in `each_with_object` not return the correct value:

```
[1,2,3].each_with_object(0) {|i,o| o += i }
# => 0
```

but using an empty array and `reduce(:+)` does?

```
[1,2,3].each_with_object([]) {|i,o| o << i }.reduce(:+)                               
# => 6
```

Comment: From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object): *"returns the initially given object"*. Integers are immutable in Ruby.

Comment: BTW, `[1,2,3].each_with_object([]) {|i,o| o << i }` returns `[1,2,3]` - your second example is equivalent to `[1,2,3].reduce(:+)`

Comment: As far as I see your examples, there is no Ruby bug. This means that they are all correct. If you think certain result is correct and certain ones are not, then you are wrong. To avoid such confusion, you should not use the word "correct."

Comment: I wish the first one worked because it's more concise. Is there a shorter way to get the same result as the second example (assuming a more complex block).

Comment: You haven't shown what you mean by "correct" or "work." Describe your expected result. In what sense is the first one not "correct" or  not "working"? OK, your comment says you want the same result as the second one, but that is what you should have written in the question from the beginning.

Comment: @ReedG.Law depends on your block. For binary operations, you'd use `reduce`.

Comment: I might want to put a conditional in the block. The initial array would more likely be objects with methods that I would call inside the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) it says:

```
each_with_object(obj) → an_enumerator
Iterates the given block for each element with an arbitrary object given, and returns the initially given object.

If no block is given, returns an enumerator.
```

As Array is an the same initial object, but with modified values is being returned in this case.

If we see the [code](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object) of each_with_object, It is:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb, line 79
  def each_with_object(memo)
    return to_enum :each_with_object, memo unless block_given?
    each do |element|
      yield element, memo
    end
    memo
  end
```

You can see, It don't modifies memo, so if memo is `0` and you change it in the code block, It will still return zero, but if you pass `[]` and change it inside code block, It will return array with values.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Ruby bug in your examples, which means they are all correct.

In the first example, the argument `0` is the return value. In the second example, the argument (that appears to be `[]` initially) is the return value. Only in the latter, the argument had been modified, and ended up looking different from what it looked like at the beginning, but the identity of the object is retained.